# How to get path variable in express(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get value of path variable **"userId"** using **req.params** but i am getting **undefined**, if any one can guide me in this problem i ll be very thankful to him. i have place my code below. 
i have go through some example but those examples are also doing in this way i don't know what is going wrong with my code.
thank you,

parent router for controller

```
app.use("/user/:userId/group",groupController);
```

Action In Controller

```
Router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {

    var group = new Group(req.body);

    console.log(req.params);

    group.userId = req.params.userId;

    group.save(new dataCallbacks(req, res, next, "Group").insert());
});
```

Comment: Uhm, what does the first route have to do with the second one that only gets the root POST requests ?

Comment: It won't post on root if he uses it with `app.use(..)`

Comment: @adeneo, first one is parent root for controller and second one is action with "/" path to post

Comment: @BidhanA i am using "/" path in action to post

Answer (score 25):

I think you are wrong with your route, you can't route to `/user/:userId/group` and post to `/` that doesn't make sense. I mean to get `userId`param, you should post to `/user/:userId/group`:

Route file `route.js`:

```
var ctrl = require('controller.js');

app.route('/user/:userId/group').post(ctrl.doIt);
```

Controller file `controller.js`:

```
exports.doIt = function(req, res, next) {
    var group = new Group(req.body);

    console.log(req.params);

    group.userId = req.params.userId;

    group.save(new dataCallbacks(req, res, next, "Group").insert());
});
```

Comment: i am using separate file for controller i cant do in this way

Comment: I think you could change the post route into a middleware, and do something like `app.use("/user/:userId/group",require('./path-to/groupController');`
Note: I would write seperate routes for the http verbs, ie. `get`, `post`/ `put`, `delete`

Comment: Edited the answer to have functions on different files

Comment: @Michelem but this ll damage my framework i ll have to register specific action in app.js which i am trying to avoid. i need a generic solution because i have to develop bundles of Api in this way

Comment: I can't understand your point. This works and this is how you should do it (in one or more files doesn't matter what matter is you can't send post to / and expect to get userId params that's defined in another route).

Comment: @Michelem i can move full URL in action handler. but i am trying to avoid this approach